# Unit test for typescript on eclipse platform

Tags: eclipse, typescript

I wonder if there is a way to test typescript code on the eclipse platform? I am thinking of something like JUnit. But the applications I have found so far is only targeting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for that you use unit testing frameworks that are IDE/platform agnostic. For example [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html). You can run it anywhere from command line, and if you want - use something like - [jasmine-junit-runner](https://github.com/wgroeneveld/jasmine-junit-runner)